# Using Excel's comparison operator in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to figure out how I can use the same comparison operator that Excel uses in sorting a mix of alphanumeric values like the following:

```
0
9
34
51
123abc
15
a
a1b23c
i
z
34ui
10
d
1
12
```

When sorting this, this is the result:

```
0
1
9
10
12
15
34
51
123abc
34ui
a
a1b23c
d
i
z
```

Is it possible to use the comparison operator that Excel uses to get this result?  Or is it necessary to create my own function for this?

Comment: The `<=` operator of VBA does this. That is, compare numbers with usual order, strings with lexicographic order, and numbers are "less than" strings.

Comment: See: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/SortingArrays.aspx

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Unfortunately, no it doesn't do that as comparing the strings "9" <= "12" comes out to be false.

Comment: @Mike Looks like they created their own function for this too, so it seems like there isn't one available from Excel's API.  That's a shame.  Not that it's hard to recreate, but seems pointless.

Comment: @supercheetah Yes, it's [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order): First compare the first letters ("9" and "1"), and since "9" > "1", your test is false. A number enclosed in double quotes is not a number, from Excel's viewpoint, it's a character string. The order for characters is [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I get that, but that's not what Excel is doing in its sort here, otherwise 10, 12, and 15 would all come before 9 in its sorting.

Comment: @supercheetah Ah, yes, sorry. Excel can sort either like I wrote above, or "treating string as numbers" when a string is like a number. This one is slightly not much more difficult, but you have to parse strings (convert to number, and if it fails treat as string). Alternately, you may create a temporary worksheet, do your stuff in it, call Excel's sort, and delete the worksheet when you're done. Not very clean, but easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just went ahead and created a comparison function with the same return values as `StrComp()` since it seems there isn't one already.

```
Function ExcelCompare(ByVal str1 As String, ByVal str2) As Integer
    Dim isnum1 As Boolean
    Dim isnum2 As Boolean
    isnum1 = IsNumeric(str1)
    isnum2 = IsNumeric(str2)
    ExcelCompare = StrComp(str1, str2)
    If isnum1 And Not isnum2 Then
        ExcelCompare = -1
    ElseIf Not isnum1 And isnum2 Then
        ExcelCompare = 1
    ElseIf isnum1 And isnum2 Then
        Dim num1 As Double
        Dim num2 As Double
        num1 = CDbl(str1)
        num2 = CDbl(str2)
        If num1 = num2 Then
            ExcelCompare = 0
        ElseIf num1 < num2 Then
            ExcelCompare = -1
        Else
            ExcelCompare = 1
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: There may be a problem with CLng, if you have strings representing floating point numbers (loss in both range and precision). CDbl is probably better suited.

Comment: I thought that [IsNumeric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6cd3f6w1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) only served to check type, but you are perfectly right to use it, the doc reads: *It also returns True if Expression is a Char or String that can be successfully converted to a number.* Thanks to have pointed me to this other usage!

Comment: I made a comment about this, but it seems to have disappeared.  @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Yes, that's a good point.  Edited.